# how to change int data type categorical data to numeric data in Python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have a data set containing columns: Deviation from Partisanship, Democrat, Disagreement with Party on Social Issues, gss year for this respondent. Deviation from Partisanship, Democrat, Disagreement with Party on Social Issues were available in Object datatype so I had to convert them in to string to encode them into numeric data.

'gss year for this respondent'contains year from 1970 - 2000 and available in int data type so I am not converting it to string to perform encoding. following is the code that I am using:

```
 #importing libraires
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

#importing data sets
df = pd.read_excel('sec3_data.xlsx')
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

#converting categorical data to numeric data.
df['Deviation from Partisanship'] = df['Deviation from Partisanship'].astype('str') 
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Deviation from Partisanship'] = le.fit_transform(df['Deviation from Partisanship'])

df['Democrat'] = df['Democrat'].astype('str') 
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Democrat'] = le.fit_transform(df['Democrat'])

df['Disagreement with Party on Social Issues'] = df['Disagreement with Party on Social Issues'].astype('str') 
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Disagreement with Party on Social Issues'] = le.fit_transform(df['Disagreement with Party on Social Issues'])

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['gss year for this respondent'] = le.fit_transform(df['gss year for this respondent'])

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 164)
df
```

When I run this code it gives me following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'gss year for this respondent'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-fbfcad1e7a05> in <module>
     13 
     14 le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
---> 15 df['gss year for this respondent'] = le.fit_transform(df['gss year for this respondent'])
     16 
     17 pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 164)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2978             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2979                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2980             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2981             if is_integer(indexer):
   2982                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
-> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'gss year for this respondent'
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

[image: Here is the image of the data frame!]

Comment: looks like you spelling it wrong maybe? you can chage with: `df.columns`

Comment: spelling is correct. How can I change it to df.columns?

Comment: Just wondering if encoding int data type can be a issue?

Comment: enconding int values also works, only mixed column types are an issue

Comment: I mean you can check the spelling with `df.columns`

Comment: Checked. No issue with the spelling.

Comment: another checkup is df.dtypes to see which column type it is

Comment: data type is int for gss year for this respondent column

Comment: can you share the results of df.columns? This error is consistent with referencing a DataFrame column which does not exist. You can quickly check whether the column you are referencing exists in your DataFrame or not by `'gss year for this respondent' in df.columns`

Comment: Umm it's weird 'gss year for this respondent' in df.columns shows false. While I can see it clearly that it is present on data frame. Attaching a pic of data frame on question please check.

Comment: found the error. There was white spaces in the column name.

Comment: Great! I have posted my comment as an answer as well. Please accept it as an answer for the benefit of others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Re-posting my own comment as an answer to benefit others quickly.

This type of error is consistent with referencing a DataFrame column which does not exist. You can quickly check whether the column you are referencing exists in your DataFrame or not by `'<COLUMN_NAME>' in df.columns`. It should return True if the column exists.

Comment: Can the down-voter help me understand what did I do wrong? So I can try to be a more useful member of the community.